# Active Record NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am getting an error when running this following command, and I can't figure out why. I am going through this online tutorial and everything works identically for me up until 16.55 minutes in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EU98yHB-_7A#t=1017).

I was trying my own things, it didn't work so I thought I would restart from scratch and have done so multiple times.

richie.car.create(:year => 2012, :condition => 'awesome')

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `richie' for main:Object
from (irb):5
from /Users/kylekozma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from /Users/kylekozma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /Users/kylekozma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
from /Users/kylekozma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
from /Users/kylekozma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/kylekozma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /Users/kylekozma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
from /Users/kylekozma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/kylekozma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /Users/kylekozma/testapp/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/kylekozma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
from /Users/kylekozma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
from /Users/kylekozma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/kylekozma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
from /Users/kylekozma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
from /Users/kylekozma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
from /Users/kylekozma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:180:in `block in serve'
from /Users/kylekozma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `fork'
from /Users/kylekozma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
from /Users/kylekozma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:128:in `block in run'
from /Users/kylekozma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `loop'
from /Users/kylekozma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `run'
from /Users/kylekozma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/kylekozma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/kylekozma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

However when I use the following code to test it is working. However the following isn't showing up in the video, but shows up for me.

```
 ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []

 User.last.cars
 User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  Car Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars"  WHERE "cars"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id",        2]]
   => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []> 
 2.1.4 :010 >
```

Comment: Your `richie` object isn't instantiated.  It sounds like you're missing a `richie = User.find...` before the line you quoted

Comment: From what I'm seeing in the video, you must be missing the `richie = User.last` line

Comment: Awesome that helps! What is the purpose of identifying richie as equal to User.last? Maybe this is a bad example of it's use, but if I enter an new user it will assign to the last user entered.

Comment: Yes.  Normally, you would do something more along the lines of `User.find(id)` where "id" is a numeric id from your parameters.